What "documentary" is Miles referring to?
In Spider-Man Into the Spider-Verse (2018) Alternate Universe Cut Peter Parker and Miles Morales are heading towards the Super-collider:

Peter: Step One: I infiltrate the lab. Two: Find the head scientist's computer.
Miles: That lady with the bike is the head scientist. I saw her in this
documentary.

What "documentary" is Miles referring to ?

Miles sees her in the documentary at the start of the film. She's talking about a grant from the Fisk Foundation for her work.



Per the screenplay:

INT. VISIONS ACADEMY CLASSROOM - DAY
Students sit in a DARKENED CLASSROOM, lit only by a large
screen playing a DOCUMENTARY.
PHYSICIST: --countless other possibilities. There could be a universe where I am wearing red. Or wearing leather pants--
...
Onscreen is a PHYSICIST, identified as “Director, Alchemax
Laboratories.” She’s the consummate nerd and AMPED about
physics.
PHYSICIST: Our universe is in fact one of many parallel universes happening at the exact same time. Thanks to everyone here at the Fisk Family Foundation
for the Sciences, I will prove they exist when I build my supercollider. All I need is 10 billion dollars. Chump change, right?


The documentary that is being shown in the class where he's trying to sneak in because he is late, near the start of the movie.




Can you provide a bit more evidence?

@Valorum I accepted your answer anyway.

@HaoLano - In the end I wrote my own :-)
